# Refresh the page after form submit

Tags: php, header, onclick, refresh, onsubmit

I have a button that extracts data to csv file. At the same time, after it extracts the table datas to csv file, it executes a query that TRUNCATES the data in the table. The thing is, the datas in that table is echoed in a . That's why I need to refresh the page so that the datas in the  will reset.

I tried different things like:

```
onSubmit="window.location.reload()"
onClick="history.go(0)"
```

But it doesn't refresh the page. But when I use:

```
header('location:redirect.php');
```

It did refresh, but it doesn't extract the datas to csv file anymore. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put `header("Location: index.php"); exit();` after the extraction of the CSV.

Comment: It did refresh but there's no extraction happened.